# Finding a special class of distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Do the distributions with the following property belong to a particular class of distributions?: the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a random variable with mean $\mu$ satisfies
>
> $$F(x)\geq 1-e^{- x/\mu},$$
>
> in other words, it is lower bounded by the CDF of an exponential random variable with the same mean $\mu$.

Does it have a name? I cannot think of well-known examples of distributions that satisfy this, do they have a special name?

Comment: Did you mean to put the inequality in the opposite direction, since you said "upper bounded"?

Comment: @angryavian thnks. i meant lower bounded.